# My app is not displaying properly based upon auto rotation

Tags: android, layout

Hi I have horizontal layout in that have vertically 3 attributes have one id view,image and then text.

while, rotating a screen on either landscape/portrait not displaying properly

In Landscape not showing full layout.
In Portrait right side space is coming.

But want adjust like full screen either portrait or landscape.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#1c1c1c"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:background="#212121">

                                <View
                                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                                    android:layout_height="7dp"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:background="#a1979e" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/img_tick1"
                                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/classic"
                                    android:visibility="visible" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txt_classic"
                                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="Classic"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorClassic"
                                    android:textSize="20sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:background="#212121">

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="7dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="#efb614" />

                            <ImageView

                                android:id="@+id/img_tick2"
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/casual1" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt_casual"
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Casual"
                                android:textColor="#efb614"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </LinearLayout>



                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:background="#212121">

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="7dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="#32cc5d" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/img_tick3"
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/natural"
                                android:visibility="visible" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt_natural"
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Natural"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorNatural"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />


                        </LinearLayout>




                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:background="#212121">

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="7dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="#ede925" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/img_tick4"
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/smart"
                                android:visibility="visible" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt_smart"
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Smart"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorSmart"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />


                        </LinearLayout>



                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:background="#212121">

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="7dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="#28dce5" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/img_tick5"
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/meeting"
                                android:visibility="visible" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt_meeting"
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Meeting"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorMeeting"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />



                    </LinearLayout>



                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:background="#212121">

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="7dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="#2a9ed1" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/img_tick6"
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/cool"
                                android:visibility="visible" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt_cool"
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Cool"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorCool"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />


                        </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: At least provide two images for what you need exactly and what you get.

Comment: i have posted my screen

Comment: Simply use weight property.

Comment: You need all 6 items get shown in portrait and landscape? Full width? If yes this means more condensed views in portrait mode. It's that what you want?